# best way to optimize django critical render path

Tags: django

I have a view which for every request will do some calculations about 1 second and then send result to render template function (return an html response).

As noted [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/measure-crp) the html header section should be sent as early as possible to let browser start downloading other blocking assets (CSS) while downloading rest of html. It also minimizes time of showing First Paint, FCP which will improve user experience.

In django by using `render` function we will send entire result after all calculation is done:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

def view(request):
    # calculate context (it may take about 1 seconds)
    return render(request, 'result.html', context)
```

What is the best way to send html header response as early as possible?

I know about `StreamingHttpResponse` but I'm not sure if it's a good fit for this problem ([django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse): You might want to do this if generating the response takes too long or uses too much memory. For instance, it’s useful for generating large CSV files.)